# How to handle ridiculous comments?

Tags: vb6, comments

Working in a classic VB6 app, crazy comments by the thousands.

Example:

```
If garrFilePaths(i).FilePath = "" Then<br>
   'do nothing
Else
   MsgBox "File Not Found (" & garrFilePaths(i).FilePath & ")", vbOKOnly, gcstrMessageBoxTitle
End If
```

Comment: What was the question again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If garrFilePaths(i).FilePath = "" Then
'do nothing 'fool
Else
MsgBox "File Not Found (" & garrFilePaths(i).FilePath & ")", vbOKOnly, gcstrMessageBoxTitle
End If
```

Answer (score 5):

Restructure the code and delete them.

```
If Not (garrFilePaths(i).FilePath = "") Then
    MsgBox "File Not Found (" & garrFilePaths(i).FilePath & ")", vbOKOnly, gcstrMessageBoxTitle
End If
```

This often works for comments that *do* make sense too.

Comment: It was a while since I did Basic, but I think that could be garrFilePaths(i).FilePath <> "".

Comment: @legoscia: Yes, I just confirmed, that would be equivalent syntax.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2hxce09y.aspx It took me an embarrassingly long time to figure out how to search for `<>`. :)

Comment: This is not equivalent condition, especially if `On Error Resume Next` is used.

Comment: @wqw: How is this not equivalent to the code in the question?

Answer (score 2):

Refactor so it makes sense. Not a lot to "handle", just remove the cruft so you don't have to spend brain-cycles on it.

Perhaps talk to the developer who wrote it, and/or work on guiding documents (coding standards) to help people do the right thing.